# "mejor A que B" vs. "prefirió A a B"

Tags: uso-de-palabras, modismos

I recently encountered in text "prefirió ser A a disfrutar B" which is a construct I have never seen before.  I was taught and have often encountered "mejor A que B."  Is the new-to-me former phrase an idiom with preferir, or is it more common?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hay diversas formas de expresar comparaciones en lo que concierne a los gustos, elecciones o preferencias. '*Es mejor ... que ...*' y '*prefiero ... a/que ...*', ambos predicados son usados porque sus connotaciones son algo diferentes—aunque probablemente sean intercambiables en muchos casos. En el primer caso estarías indicando una elección objetiva e impersonal, que no solo referiría a *tu* punto de vista, si no a una creencia aceptada por la sociedad en general. Mientras que en el segundo caso no das a entender que la preferencia pueda ser generalizada ni extenderse más allá de tu propia subjetividad. Compará estos ejemplos:

> **Prefiero** los fideos a los ravioles.

> Si intentan robarte, **es mejor** entregar tus pertenencias antes que defenderte y arriesgar tu vida.

¿Notás la diferencia? Sonaría muy arriesgado si afirmara que 'los fideos son mejores que los ravioles', pero en el segundo caso no creo que quienes hayan leído la afirmación tengan demasiada dificultad en coincidir con la misma, o al menos en reconocer que suena razonable.

Ahora bien, para el caso de *prefiero* hay que considerar que la expresión a utilizar puede ser '**prefiero** A **a** B', o bien '**prefiero** A **que** B'. En pocas palabras, la primera expresión suele usarse cuando B pertenece a un grupo nominal—sustantivo o pronombre—mientras que la segunda expresion se prefiere en los demás casos—cuando B es un verbo infinitivo o un adverbio que hace de objeto en la oración. La regla explicada con mayor detalle la podés encontrar [en el sitio de la RAE](https://www.rae.es/dpd/preferir).

Ayuda: el uso para ambas expresiones es muy similar al empleado en el inglés

- 'A es mejor que B' = 'A is better than B'
- 'es mejor A que B' = 'is better A than B' (si la inversión es válida)
- 'prefiero A a/que B' = '(I) prefer A to B'

Comment: Lo que sí no recuerdo es si en el inglés se dice 'I prefer A to B' o bien sería 'I prefer A than B'

Comment: It is "[I prefer A to B](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/123665/400257)"

Comment: Gracias por el enlace RAE

Comment: We also say "I'd rather A than B". We also would say "I would prefer to be happy in poverty than rich and miserable" so prefer than is possible although I have zero knowledge of the rule involved here, I just speak English I do not know any of the rules.

Comment: @mdewey, "rule" is a very poorly chosen word.  What is commonly called grammar "rules" are really descriptions of how people speak.  Just like the "law" of gravity is actually a description of what happens.  (So "law" is also poorly chosen there)

Comment: @WGroleau I meant the observed regularities but I could not think of a name for them.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean _you_ made a bad choice.  Just that "we" (English speakers in general log ago) adopted a word unfortunately that misleads people by making them think grammar is some sort of legislation.

Answer (score 0):

The big difference is that in "mejor A que B" you don't have a verb, while in "prefirió ser A a disfrutar B"  you have three different verbs: Preferir (to prefer), ser (to be), and disfrutar (to enjoy).

"Mejor A que B" can be translated as "Better A than B", there is a implicit verb that is understood through context, for example "Better *to be* A than *to be* B" (1)  or  "Better to enjoy A than to enjoy B" (2). On the other hand "prefirió ser A a disfrutar B" can be translated as "I prefer to be A than to enjoy B" (3). Sentence (3) compares the first term of (1) with the second term of (2); it compares to be A with to enjoy B.